# Change text on basis of condition

Tags: angular

I want to have div on basis of weather `isTranscript is true or false`. The value of `isTranscript` is changing in code process but `div` does not rendered accordingly. When page loads `div` is there as value is false but when `isTranscript` becomes `false`, `div` is still there

Method which changes isTranscript

```js
isTranscript = false
  handleRegenerateTranscript() {
    this.isTranscript = false;
    this.requestStatus.isLoading = true;
    this.transcriptService.regenerateTranscript(this.videoId).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.englishTranscriptArr = data;
        this.requestStatus.isLoading = false;
        this.isTranscript = true;
        this.requestStatus.isError = false;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.requestStatus.isLoading = false;
        this.requestStatus.isError = true;
        this.isTranscript = true;
        this.requestStatus.error = error.error.message;
        Swal({
          type: "error",
          title: `Oops... ${error.error.name}!`,
          text: error.error.message,
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Div dependent on `isTranscript`.

```html
<div *ngIf="!isTranscript">Generating Transcript...</div>
```

Comment: Attach debugger and check if value for `isTranscript` is really changing. Also if you are using `onPush` strategy make sure to detect changes by change detector.

Comment: yes isTranscript is changing

Answer (score 0):

I guess change detection is not triggered in your case.
Try manually trigger it.

```
constructor(
   :
  private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
   :
)

isTranscript = false
  handleRegenerateTranscript() {
    this.isTranscript = false;
    this.requestStatus.isLoading = true;
    this.transcriptService.regenerateTranscript(this.videoId).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.englishTranscriptArr = data;
        this.requestStatus.isLoading = false;
        this.isTranscript = true;
        this.requestStatus.isError = false;
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // Add this line.
      },
      (error) => {
        this.requestStatus.isLoading = false;
        this.requestStatus.isError = true;
        this.isTranscript = true;
        this.requestStatus.error = error.error.message;
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // Add this line.
        Swal({
          type: "error",
          title: `Oops... ${error.error.name}!`,
          text: error.error.message,
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"**When page loads div is there as value is false but when isTranscript becomes false, div is still there.**" According to your condition the Div will render when isTranscript = false. What do you think?